# React native: How to import a functional component if it is not exported as default

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm not able to move the SignIn screen from the index.js file to Screens.js file
I have been following the default react-navigation documentation and after getting the first example up an running I renamed the HomeScreen to SignIn. This worked. The second step for me was to move the SignIn screen from index.js to Screens.js

### This works

#### index.js

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

//import { SignIn } from "./Screens";

export const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Sign in</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <AuthStack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
      </AuthStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Screens.js

```js
import Rreact from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export const SignIn = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Sign in</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

---

### This does not work

I'm trying to use the SignIn component from the Screens.js file like so

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import { SignIn } from "./Screens";

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <AuthStack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
      </AuthStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the error
[image: Emulator screen]

Could someone explain to me what am I missing?

Comment: In ```Screen.js```, you have a typo: ```import Rreact from "react";```. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Screens.js change the following line

```
import Rreact from "react";
```

to

```
import React from "react";
```